# Swift 3.0 UserDefaults get value error

Tags: swift, swift3, nsuserdefaults

This piece of code never calls "do something", but `Int` for key is stored at `UserDefaults`.

```
if UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "prefix_\(item.value(forKey: "someKey") as! String)") == 1 {
    //do something
}
```

If I change code to:

```
let key = "prefix_\(item.value(forKey: "someKey") as! String)"
if UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: key) == 1 {
    do something
 }
```

It works great! What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

This is my example and its working fine with your Values.

I assume, "item" is NSDictionary.

**it work for me this**

```
    let item : NSDictionary = ["someKey":"123"]

    let key = "prefix_\(item.value(forKey: "someKey") as! String)"
    if UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: key) == 1 {
        // do some thing
    }
```

**And As well as this too**

```
    let item : NSDictionary = ["someKey":"123"]

    if UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "prefix_\(item.value(forKey: "someKey") as! String)") == 1 {
        // do some thing
    }
```

I think you must be making mistake in copy, or missing any `)` or `"` .